# Sending message does not work in XMPP with Smack library

Tags: java, android, xmpp, chat, smack

#### Problem Description

I'm writing chat application using XMPP and Smack Android library. I'm sending messages using code below and everything is working fine.

```
final ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
chatManager.addChatListener(this); 
....

@Override
public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
    chat.addMessageListener(this);
}

@Override
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    // Do something here.
}

Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(jid);
chat.sendMessage("message");
```

#### Question

Unfortunately the API above is deprecated `org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat` and instead I should use `org.jivesoftware.smack.chat2.Chat`, so I am changing implementation as follows

```
final ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
chatManager.addOutgoingListener(this);
chatManager.addIncomingListener(this);
....
Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).chatWith(jid);
chat.send("message");
```

In this case I can still get Incoming messages, but when I am trying to send message with `chat.send("message");` server does not get anything and `addOutgoingListener` callback is not called.

Any ideas why?

Comment: In the line `Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(jid);`, how do you get the `jid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

Digging a bit deeper I found the answer, the code below will help to send a message

#### Sending Message Code

```
final Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).chatWith(jid);

Message newMessage = new Message(jid, Message.Type.chat);
newMessage.setBody(message);

chat.send(newMessage);
```

#### Conclusion

So instead of sending a string message, you need to create a `Message` object and I think what is more important is to specify `Message.Type.chat` in the constructor and also `jid` and then call `chat.send(...)`

Answer (score 2):

There is an example with an older version of smack:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws XMPPException {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 5222);    
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config); 
        connection.connect();   
        connection.login("userx", "123456");
        ChatManager cm = connection.getChatManager(); 
        Chat chat = cm.createChat("tongqian@tsw-PC", null);
        /*
         * add listener
         */
        cm.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean create) {
                chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
                        System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + ":" + msg.getBody());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        chat.sendMessage("hello");  
        while(true);        
        //connection.disconnect();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this code snippet:

> ```java
> public void sendMessage(String to, Message newMessage) {
> if(chatManager!=null) {
> Chat newChat = chatManager.createChat(to);
>
> try {
> if (connection.isConnected() && connection.isAuthenticated()) {
>
> newChat.sendMessage(newMessage);
> }
> } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
> e.printStackTrace();
> }
> }
> else
> {
> Log.d(TAG,”chatmanager is null”);
> }
> }
> ```

And the link is https://ramzandroidarchive.wordpress.com/2016/03/13/send-messages-over-xmpp-using-smack-4-1/ .